# C++ casting int to double

Tags: c++, casting

I'm not a C++ developer, but today I've found a C++ code and try to understand it. So I've stacked on this piece of code:

```
int m = 2, n = 3, i = 1;
double mid = (double)m / n * i;
int d = (int)mid + 1;

printf("%d %d\n", mid, d);
```

The result which is going to be printed to the console is: 1431655765 1071994197. It seems to be related with the casting of variable m to double, but I have no idea how it is happening. I need someone to help me understand it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: the title of this question seems not to match what it's really about.

Comment: [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) is the doc page about type casting.

Comment: c++? then better to use `static_cast<double>(m)` instead of old style `(double) m`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should print a double(`mid`) with the `%lf` format specifier in `printf`.

Comment: The format specifier for output should be `%f`; that applies to both float and double, since floats are promoted to double when passed through an ellipsis. `%lf` is not valid. For `scanf`, `%f` means float, `%lf` means double, and `%Lf` means long double.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the printf to

```
printf("%f %i\n", mid, d);
```

will actually print what you expect i.e., 0.666667 1

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to solve it would be

```
double m_Doubled;
m_Doubled = static_cast(m);
```